# Replace an IP address with it's whois using bash

Tags: bash

I have a traffic log similar to this

"page visited" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2013-10-30

and I would like to replace the ip address with the result of it's whois lookup.

I can export the ip addresses to a separate file and then do a whois on each line, but im struggling to combine them all together.

Ideally i'd like to replace the ip address in the same string and print the new string to a new file.

So it would look like

"page visited" for example.com at 2013-10-30

Can anyone help

Here's what I have so far

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' clean_cites.txt > iplist.txt
for i in `cat iplist.txt`
do
OUTPUT=$(geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPOrg.dat $i)
echo $i,$OUTPUT >> visited.txt
done
```

Like I said,this produces a separate file with a list of ip addresses and their relevant hostnames, so I either need to search for the ip address in file and and replace it with the text in file b (which will give the ip address and hostname) or replace the ip address in place.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your script so far?

Comment: what if there's more than one DNS name?

Comment: Not exactly related to solving your problem. but what does your `geoiplookup` output? GeoIP databases usually only provide geographic location information which doesn't appear to be what you're after. The normal method used by most software to resolve IP addresses is to get reverse DNS with something like `dig +short -x a.b.c.d`. Not all IP addresses have reverse DNS though.

Comment: It outputs the name of who the ip address belongs to...we've purchased the extra database.

Comment: For clarity - there is an edition of [MaxMind's GeoIP Database that supports domain resolution](http://www.maxmind.com/en/domain). Is this what you're using?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to save the IP addresses to a temporary file. You don't even need to use `grep` since Bash 3.2 and greater supports regexes (3.1 also does, but the features were changed in 3.2).

```
#!/bin/bash
ip_pattern='([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}'
while read -r line
do
    [[ line =~ $ip_pattern ]]
    ip=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    domain=$(geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPOrg.dat "$ip")
    echo "${line//$ip/$domain}" # substitute the domain for the ip in the original line
done < clean_cites.txt > outputfile.txt
```

This should run faster since you don't have to spawn `grep` for every line and you're not having to iterate over the file twice (or two or more files).

You should never do `for i in cat` by the way, use `while read -r` instead.

Make it a habit to use mixed case or lower case variable names in order to avoid potential name collision with shell variables.